# UIImage masking gives black background on the iPhone (and not in simulator)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage, mask

I've got mask images w/o alpha channel, pure black and white with a black polygone on the center sourrounded by white.

I've got png's image that I'd like to mask. the png have got an alpha channel.
using the method here below : ok on simulator, but background is black on device ... 
any idea to fix that ?

```
- (UIImage*) maskImage:(UIImage *)image withMask:(UIImage *)maskImage {

CGImageRef maskRef = maskImage.CGImage; 

CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), NULL, false);

CGImageRef masked = CGImageCreateWithMask([image CGImage], mask);

//CGImageRelease(mask);
//CGImageRelease(maskRef);
return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:masked];
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem Solved :
solution is : the image to be masked MUST be created with an alpha channel.
The Alpha channel may not be created from the code.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. could you post some code sample on how to create the alpha channel?

Comment: Thanks Tibi. For me it was also important that the maskImage has an alpha channel.
So since iOS7 BOTH images, the image to be masked and the mask itself must have an alpha channel.

Answer (score 0):

Same here with the following code

```
- (UIImage*)maskImage:(UIImage *)image withMask:(UIImage *)maskImage {
CGImageRef maskRef = maskImage.CGImage;
CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), NULL, false);

CGImageRef sourceImage = [image CGImage];
CGImageRef imageWithAlpha = sourceImage;
//add alpha channel for images that don't have one (ie GIF, JPEG, etc...)
//this however has a computational cost
if (CGImageGetAlphaInfo(sourceImage) == kCGImageAlphaNone) { 
    imageWithAlpha = CopyImageAndAddAlphaChannel(sourceImage);
}

CGImageRef masked = CGImageCreateWithMask(imageWithAlpha, mask);
//const float colorMasking[6] = { 100,100, 100, 250,250, 250};
//CGImageRef maskedImageRef = CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors(temp.CGImage, colorMasking); 
CGImageRelease(mask);

//release imageWithAlpha if it was created by CopyImageAndAddAlphaChannel
if (sourceImage != imageWithAlpha) {
    CGImageRelease(imageWithAlpha);
}

UIImage* retImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:masked];
CGImageRelease(masked);

return retImage;
```

}

```
CGImageRef CopyImageAndAddAlphaChannel(CGImageRef sourceImage) {
CGImageRef retVal = NULL;

size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(sourceImage);
size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(sourceImage);

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

CGContextRef offscreenContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width, height, 
                                                      8, 0, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

if (offscreenContext != NULL) {
    CGContextDrawImage(offscreenContext, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), sourceImage);

    retVal = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(offscreenContext);
    CGContextRelease(offscreenContext);
}

CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

return retVal;
```

}

Works perfectly on simulator but not  on iPhone device : all images are masked but with black background.

Comment: I used you your code and I think the problem is the line "CGImageGetAlphaInfo(sourceImage) == kCGImageAlphaNone". In my case this was always false, forcing not!! to add a alpha channel. Adding the alpha channel always worked.