# UIImage mask with transparent borders

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am using this method to mask a `UIImage`:

```
UIImage *inputImage = [UIImage imageName:@"inputImage.png"];
CGImageRef maskRef = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mask.png"].CGImage; 

CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), NULL, false);

CGImageRef masked = CGImageCreateWithMask([inputImage CGImage], mask);
CGImageRelease(mask);

UIImage *maskedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:masked];

CGImageRelease(masked);
```

This is the mask image:

[image]

And the problem is that when I mask the image the border is in black, it is possible to make the border transparent?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIImage masking gives black background on the iPhone (and not in simulator)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297994/uiimage-masking-gives-black-background-on-the-iphone-and-not-in-simulator)

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978847/how-to-smoothen-the-edges-of-a-uiimageview-in-ios

Comment: Two of this wo'nt work